# Copy cells' content w/o adding quotes - Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers, copy-paste, text

I want to copy text from a cell, exactly as it is. However, Numbers (3.6.2) put quotes around my text.

**Example:**

> This is text inside a cell.

When trying to paste the string that I've just copied into TextEdit for instance, I'm left with this:

> "This is text inside a cell."

Any way to prevent Numbers from doing that?

Comment: Why do you think it's Numbers and not TextEdit that's adding the quotes (when it recognizes a text string)?

Comment: Cause I can paste it no matter where and it already has the quotes.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this in Numbers 4.0.5, but it did not happen. Is there a reason you're not updating Numbers? If not, try updating the app.

Comment: I seem to have found the issue. Some of my cells included line breaks. Only text of those were quoted. Try reproducing that.